# How can you prove the analyticity of this function using Cauchy-Riemann Equations

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

Let $$f_{\varepsilon,+} = \frac{i}{\pi}\oint_{L_\varepsilon,+}\frac{h(t)}{t-z}dz$$

Assuming there's enough regularity and all hypothesis are satisfied for the derivatives to go through the integral. How can you prove its analytic?

Comment: Instead of CR equations, it is usually easier to use [Morera's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morera's_theorem) to justify a function is holomorphic. For your case, it comes down to justify one can exchange the order of integration (which tends to be simpler than showing one can differentiate under integral sign).

Comment: Thanks for the information, I haven't been taught Morera's Theorem yet. That's why it has all those extra hypothesis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under your hypotheses all is noise but $\frac1{t-z} $. You need the real and imaginary parts $u$ and $v$:
$$
2u=2\operatorname{Re} \frac1{t-z} =\frac1{t-z} +\frac1{t-\overline z} =\frac{z+\overline z} {t^2+|z|^2-2\operatorname{Re}tz}=\frac{2x}{t^2+x^2+y^2-2tx},
$$
$$
2iv=2i\operatorname{Im} \frac1{t-z} =\frac1{t-z} - \frac1{t-\overline z} =\frac{z-\overline z} {t^2+|z|^2-2\operatorname{Re}tz}=\frac{2iy}{t^2+x^2+y^2-2tx}.
$$
Now you can check directly that $u$ and $v$ satisfy the Cauchy-Riemnan equations.

Comment: Of course!! I didn't think about forgetting everything else. Thanks a lot.